# Trying to connect to a SQL Server 2000 instance via SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server, remote-access

All --
       I have a development VM server with Windows Server 2008-R2 and on it I have the following versions of SQL Server Installed:

- SQL 2000 - Developer Edition
- SQL 2005 - Enterprise Edition
- SQL 2008-R1 - Enterprise Edition
- SQL 2008-R2 - Enterprise Edition
- SQL 2012 - Enterprise Edition

Each of these SQL Instances are named instances where I use the Version number in the name such as:

- ServerName\SQL2K0
- ServerName\SQL2K5

I am able to access all of these instances from the local machine without any issues and with the exception of the SQL 2000 instance I can access (login) all of them from a remote machine using SSMS 2012. I am not able to access the 2000 instance using SSMS 2012 remotely but strangely I am able to access the SQL 2000 instance with SSMS 2012 Locally. I am also able to access the SQL 2000 instance remotely using SSMS 2008-R2.

So I don't think that it is a firewall issue nor would it be an issue regarding remote access but I am out of ideas, am I missing something?

## ***UPDATE***

Ok, I finally had some time to get back to this I am still not able to access the SQL2K0 instance via SSMS 2012 but I installed SSMS 2008-R2 and I am able to connect to the SQL 2K0 instance. So now I am ready perplexed!!!!!

Comment: I found evidence disproving my answer so I deleted it and am thinking more on your problem.  Sorry for the misinfo!

Comment: On a side note, have a look at this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22833/can-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-2000-instance-from-sql-server-management-studio-20.

Comment: I installed SSMS 2008-R2 and I am now able to connect to the SQL 2K0 instance from my remote machine but I still am not able to connect using SSMS 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The native client that ships with SQL Server 2012 (11.0) does not support SQL 2000 by default any more. You may be able to get around it by creating an alias and ODBC connection to the 2K0 instance using the native client 10.0 that is packaged in 2K8 but I have not tested it.

Comment: Thanks, but like I stated earlier I am able to access the SQL 2000 instance using SSMS 2012 on the Local Server itself.